# How to display a list of strings dynamically in python

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings in python which are in form of an arithmetic problem. So:

`p_list = ['32 + 5', '4 - 1', '345 + 2390']`

I would love each of the list to be arranged in this manner

```
  32      4       345
+  5    - 1    + 2390
----    ---    ------
```

So essentially i want the numbers to be right aligned and four spaces between each expression.

I tried doing something like this

```
final = f"{final}    {problem_list[key]['operand1']}\n{problem_list[key]['operator']} {problem_list[key]['operand2']}"
```

but i got this instead

```
213
+ 4    3234
+ 4    3
- 3    5
+ 7
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to print out the equations, this function arranges them in your desired way:

```
def arithmetic_format(eq_list, sep = 4):
    top = mid = bot = ""
    sep = " " * sep
    for eq in eq_list:
        chars = eq.split()
        width = len(max(chars, key=len)) + 2
        top += chars[0].rjust(width) + sep
        mid += chars[1] + chars[2].rjust(width - 1) + sep
        bot += "-" * width + sep   
    return f"{top}\n{mid}\n{bot}"

p_list = ['32 + 5', '4 - 1', '345 + 2390']
answer = arithmetic_format(p_list)
print(answer)
```

Out:

```
  32      4       345    
+  5    - 1    + 2390    
----    ---    ------
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works perfectly but i have the code in a function. What if i want them returned and not printed. I tried returning them like `return top, mid, bot, sep="\n"` but i got a tuple. Is there a way to return them and still keep the format?

Comment: If you want to use a function and return the new format, use `return f"{top}\n{mid}\n{bot}"`. Printing this returned formatted string will result in the same answer

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here's one:

```
plist = ['32 + 5', '4 - 1', '345 + 2390']
spaces = ' ' * 4

def parts(plist):
    return [e.split() for e in plist]

def widths(plist):
    return [max(map(len, e))+2 for e in parts(plist)]

def get_tokens(plist, idx):
    if idx == 0:
        return [f'{e:>{w}}' for (e, _, _), w in zip(parts(plist), widths(plist))]
    if idx == 1:
        return [f'{s}{n:>{w-1}}' for (_, s, n), w in zip(parts(plist), widths(plist))]
    return ['-' * w for w in widths(plist)]

for idx in range(3):
    print(spaces.join(get_tokens(plist, idx)))
```

**Output:**

```
  32      4       345
+  5    - 1    + 2390
----    ---    ------
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
p_list = ['32 + 5', '4 - 1', '345 + 2390']
up= []
down=[]

for op in p_list:
    new = op.split(' ')
    up.append(new[0] + ' '*4)
    if new[1] == '-':
        down.append(str(0 - int(new[-1])) + ' '*4)
    else:
        down.append('+' + new[-1] + ' '*3)
for index,value in enumerate(up):
    print(value, end=' ')
print('')
for index,value in enumerate(down):
    print(value, end=' ')




# 32     4     345     
# +5    -1     +2390
```

Comment: Your output doesn't seem to align with OP's requirements